# How to delve down a dictionary and remove deepest key level

Tags: python, dictionary, decision-tree

Assume I have the following dictionary object:

```
dictionary = {'First_level': {0: {'Second_level0': {0.0: {'Third_level0': {0.0: 7.0, 1.0: 3.0}}}},
      2: {'Second_level1': {0.0: 2.0, 1.0: 1.0}},
      4: {'Second_level2': {0.0: {'Third_level1': {0.0: 7.0, 1.0: 5.0}}, 1.0: 1.0}},
      6: {'Second_level3': {0.0: 6.0, 1.0: 7.0}},
      'Third_level2': 7.0}}
```

This dictionary gets automatically build and I want a function which delves this dictionary down to the deepst key level, and replace this key by a default value. Here it is not given that the dictionary is three levels deep nor that the keys start with *Third_* the dictionary could also be 40 levels deep where the deepest level keys are for instance 8:0 or "A":1

The final dictionary should look smth. like:

```
dictionary = {'First_level': {0: {'Second_level0': {0.0: {'Third_level0': 1}}},
          2: {'Second_level1': {0.0: 2.0, 1.0: 1.0}},
          4: {'Second_level2': {0.0: {'Third_level1': {0.0: 7.0, 1.0: 5.0}}, 1.0: 1.0}},
          6: {'Second_level3': {0.0: 6.0, 1.0: 7.0}},
          'Third_level2': 1}}
```

Hence the items under the *Third_level0, Third_level1 and Third_level2* got replaced by a **1**

So far I have tried:

```
def delve_dictionary(dictionary=dictionary,default = 1):
for key in dictionary:
    item = dictionary[key]

    if isinstance(item,dict):

        level = delve_dictionary(item)
    else: 
        key = default

return dictionary

delve_dictionary(dictionary=dictionary,default=1)
```

But obviously this is not working...

```
{'First_level': {0: {'Second_level0': {0.0: {'Third_level0': {0.0: 7.0,
      1.0: 3.0}}}},
  2: {'Second_level1': {0.0: 2.0, 1.0: 1.0}},
  4: {'Second_level2': {0.0: {'Third_level1': {0.0: 7.0, 1.0: 5.0}},
    1.0: 1.0}},
  6: {'Second_level3': {0.0: 6.0, 1.0: 7.0}},
  'Third_level2': 7.0}}
```

Comment: your `Third_level1` is not replaced by a 1.

Comment: Is the final dictionary correct or a copy/paste error? Otherwise, cool question.

Comment: No thats indeed a copy paste error

Comment: always the deepest level or always the 3rd level? Also, your `delve_dictionary` method doesn't operate on `tree` or `testing_data`. It also never changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming every final value for `Third_level` keys should be set to `1`, you can use recursion to handle data of an arbitrary depth:

```
dictionary = {'First_level': {0: {'Second_level0': {0.0: {'Third_level0': {0.0: 7.0, 1.0: 3.0}}}},
  2: {'Second_level1': {0.0: 2.0, 1.0: 1.0}},
  4: {'Second_level2': {0.0: {'Third_level1': {0.0: 7.0, 1.0: 5.0}}, 1.0: 1.0}},
  6: {'Second_level3': {0.0: 6.0, 1.0: 7.0}},
  'Third_level2': 7.0}}

def update_dict(d):
   return {a:1 if isinstance(a, str) and a.startswith('Third_level') else update_dict(b) if isinstance(b, dict) else b for a, b in d.items()}

print(update_dict(dictionary))
```

Output:

```
{'First_level': {0: {'Second_level0': {0.0: {'Third_level0': 1}}}, 2: {'Second_level1': {0.0: 2.0, 1.0: 1.0}}, 4: {'Second_level2': {0.0: {'Third_level1': 1}, 1.0: 1.0}}, 6: {'Second_level3': {0.0: 6.0, 1.0: 7.0}}, 'Third_level2': 1}}
```

Comment: The problem is, that the dictionary is neither always three levels deep nor the deepest level starts with *Third_*

Comment: @2Obe This solution does not rely on a fixed depth, and can traverse the entire structure.

Comment: Thank you very much but it assumes that the last level starts with 'Third_level'

Answer (score 0):

Have solved the problem with:

```
def delve_dictionary(dictionary = dictionary,default = 1):
    for item in dictionary:
        try:
            if isinstance(dictionary[item],dict):
                level = delve(dictionary[item])
            else: 
                dictionary[item] = default
        except:
            ''
    return(dictionary)

delve_dictionary(dictionary=dictionary,default=1)


{'First_level': {0: {'Second_level0': {0.0: {'Third_level0': {0.0: 1,
      1.0: 1}}}},
  2: {'Second_level1': {0.0: 1, 1.0: 1}},
  4: {'Second_level2': {0.0: {'Third_level1': {0.0: 1, 1.0: 1}}, 1.0: 1}},
  6: {'Second_level3': {0.0: 1, 1.0: 1}},
  'Third_level2': 1}}
```